Why does my Voice Report praat script only go through one file of the stringlist?
I'm trying to use a praat script that extracts the voice report for each annotated segment of a tier in a series of textgrids, but the script only works for the first file on the stringlist only.
I checked both the wavlist and the gridlist and they include all the files in the folder, so praat recognises them all. I checked all the forloops were closed and all the objects assigned.
This is what the code looks like:
`clearinfo
form Enter Full Path + \ 
    sentence directory C:\Users\Lucia\Desktop\tester_scritps1\
endform

table = Create Table with column names: "table", 0, 
... "name fraction number_voice_breaks degree"

Create Strings as file list: "wavlist", directory$ + "*.wav"
number_files = Get number of strings
Create Strings as file list: "gridlist", directory$ + "*.TextGrid" 
#number_files = Get number of strings


#name and metadata

for i from 1 to number_files
    selectObject: "Strings wavlist"
    filename$ = Get string... i
    Read from file: directory$ + filename$
    name$ = filename$ - ".wav"
    selectObject: "Strings gridlist"
    filename$ = Get string... i
    Read from file: directory$ + filename$
    name$ = filename$ - ".TextGrid"

    selectObject: "Sound " + name$
    To Pitch (ac): 0, 50, 15, "yes", 0.03, 0.45, 0.01, 0.35, 0.14, 500
    f0min = 50
    f0max = 500
    

    selectObject: "Sound " + name$
    To Intensity: 75, 0.001, "yes"
    
    selectObject: "Sound " + name$
    To PointProcess (periodic, cc): f0min, f0max
selectObject: "TextGrid " + name$  
    tgObj = selected("TextGrid")
        #### (2 continued, #1)
    number_intervals = Get number of intervals: 3
    
    for i from 1 to 'number_intervals'

        selectObject: tgObj
                
     seg_label$ = Get label of interval: 3, i
   
    
    if seg_label$ != ""

        seg_start = Get start time of interval: 3, i
        seg_end = Get end time of interval: 3, i

    selectObject: "Sound " + name$, "Pitch " + name$, "PointProcess " + name$
        report$ = Voice report: seg_start, seg_end,
        ... f0min, f0max, 1.3, 1.6, 0.03, 0.45

     pctUnvoiced = extractNumber (report$, "Fraction of locally unvoiced frames: ")*100
     fracUnvoiced$ = extractLine$ (report$, "Fraction ")
     nVoicebreaks = extractNumber (report$, "Number of voice breaks: ")
     pctVoicebreaks = extractNumber (report$, "Degree of voice breaks: ") * 100
     degreeVoicebreaks$ = extractLine$ (report$, "Degree ")


    selectObject: table
    Append row
    current_row = Get number of rows
    Set string value:  current_row, "name", name$
    Set string value:  current_row, "fraction", fracUnvoiced$
    Set numeric value:  current_row, "number_voice_breaks", nVoicebreaks
    Set string value:  current_row, "degree", degreeVoicebreaks$
    
    endif
    
  endfor
  


endfor

selectObject: table
 Save as tab-separated file: directory$ + "output.txt"`

How can I fix this?
